# Why did fetch stop working - for me - on all branches in backend server?

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, express, nodemon

After a refactor, on a separate branch, fetch no longer works in any branch. Everything else works as expected. Error:

```
...server/KE/utils.ts:44
const response = await fetch(
                 ^
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

Refactor was moving logic from KE/router.ts to a function in KE/utils.ts.
fetch is present in lib.dom.d.ts.
Had a friend a friend run the code and they were able to call fetch without issue.

#### Fixes attempted

- I moved the function from KE/utils.ts logic back to KE/router.ts.
- Copied all imports from KE/router to KE/utils.
- Installed node-fetch. `Import fetch from 'node-fetch'`. Stopped compiling because as it messed with express's data types.
- Checked previous branch which used to work.
- Reinstalling all packages with npm.
- Reinstalled npm with `curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh`

#### Versions

- npm - 9.6.2
- express - 4.18.2
- vue - 3.2.47
- typescript - 4.5.5
- nodemon - 2.0.21

Comment: Your whole question/post is a mess. Focus on one thing and make a post that one thing instead of give us your whole development history/diary. Please read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You write much words, but say nothing. Focus on your problem.

Comment: Your problem is that `fetch` is not found in your backend. Focus on that and edit your question with proper details about that error message, with line numbers, see above, "How to Ask".

Comment: Check your node version (not just npm) by running `node --version`. I'm pretty sure you're not using Node 19 to run this code, which is the first Node version with built-in `fetch` support.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That fixed it. Was version 14.x. Before I write answer, any idea why that only affected backend? Frontend used fetch for the api call to backend. It was also fine for my previous 2 projects in Vue. Only error'ed after refactor (less than an hour).

I can guarantee I did not change Node version during refactor. Did not even have nvm installed.

Comment: Your front-end doesn't run through Node, it runs in the browser, and the browser has had the Fetch API [for many years](https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back-end runs on Node. Update node to a version >= 18.0.0 to fix. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

To install latest node with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

```
nvm install node
```

Credit: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans